# Checkout last step issue (Magento 1.9.3)

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on a custom theme for magento 1.9.3, and I am facing an issue with the last step of the checkout proccess (review step). It loads something meaningless which I don't understand why, it loads the main template, like the main-wrapper I have, the leftsidebar, main-content, logo, etc. But nothing inside.

This problem occurs only when trying to follow the checkout process as a guest, but when I'm logged in, it works fine.

I am not allow to share the test url publicly but I can send it as a private message.

I am new working with magento so I am not sure what could be the reason so any clue would be appreaciated.

Thanks :)

**Edited:**

Checking the var/logs I found a system.log file which has these lines that appears when trying to reproduce my issue. But don't know what that means and how to fix it.

```
2017-10-27T16:02:54+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/account/checkout/onepage/parcelannouncement.phtml
2017-10-27T16:03:05+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/paypalplus/form/payment.phtml
2017-10-27T16:03:05+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/pnsofortueberweisung/form/sofortueberweisung.phtml
2017-10-27T16:03:09+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/paypalplus/payment/info.phtml
```

Comment: @ Daniel,  Check the logs inside your var/log folder and also check your browser log()

Comment: @MGento thanks for your advice, I did check those folder and there are some errors but to be honest I don't understand which one of those is the one with the conflict.

Comment: disable all 3rd party exntension and check so you can get that which extension causes this issue

Comment: @ Daniel Soublett,  Delete your log files and do your checkout process again and then you can see, the log files are generated with errors again.  If possible, post your log files here.

Comment: @MGento I actually did that, I removed all the log files and then started the checkout process again and the errors you can see above are the only ones displayed.

Comment: @jigsparmar thanks for the advice, gonna try that and see if that's the problem.

Comment: @MGento now there are not log files when doing the checkout process again, but the problem is still there, is loading something weird. As I am creating a custom theme I also tried to copy and paste the original files from the magento installation to see if something I changed in some template was causing the conflict, but no, the problem is still there.

Comment: @jigsparmar I tried deactivating all 3rd party extensions but the problem is still there.